# Break string in Javax.Swing.JTextArea without escape characters

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to automatically break a string entered into `JTextArea` (in package `javax.swing`), for example via the keyboard, into a readable form, without the need for escape characters, i.e. `\n` and `\r` ?

Edit2:

With the help of @matt, I realized that the correct question is about word warp and therefore the answer is the answer function

```
mytextArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

Comment: Even if you use the keyboard, you’re still inserting escape characters - that’s kind of how text works

Comment: What do you mean "break a sring" Can you post a more complete example. Are you asking about word wrap? You can filter and interact with the text area while it is being edited.

Comment: @matt   exactly word wrap!, T,h,,a,n,k,s,  solved my problem by your hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking a string onto a newline without actually adding a character is a word wrap.

[JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap(boolean)) has word wrap.

```
mytextArea.setLineWrap(true);
```